# Export Photoshop Groups as separate images

Tags: javascript, scripting, web, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm currently working with several different Photoshop files. They all contain up to 10-40 Groups with even more layers. I want to export every group as an "image for web" in a different size than the document size.
Basically this is quite simple and should work like this in pseudo-code:

```
for i = layerGroups; i > 0; i--;
  export layergroup[i] for web with "width=200 and height=120"
```

I'm experienced in javascript coding, however, I've never coded a Photoshop script yet, so this is where the difficulties begin. Hopefully, I could render out my problem and get some helping hands.
Cheers

Comment: This should get you started: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf In particular check out the `LayerSets` object which the top-level array of `LayerSet` objects which are the groups you'd find in your layers palette. `LayerSet.bounds` will give you the dimensions of that set. `app.documents.add(w,h,etc)` to create a new document, etc. If you've written JavaScript you shouldn't have too much trouble, it's just a matter of learning a new API. Post specific questions with sample code if you get stuck.